# SAP Web-IDE Full Stack: how to handle configuration files

Tags: sap-web-ide, sap-cloud-platform

In SAP Web-IDE Full Stack we need to handle configuration files, typically json, that stores information that may change during application lifetime. We're looking to the proper way to change this files and fetch them from application: at the moment we store them with in the Web-IDE project, so we need to re-deploy to CF the application for each modification in configuration files (but this cannot be the correct way, if the customer needs to change the configuration on his own).

Do we need to create a custom solution to store these files and retrieve them from deployed app? Does SAP provide some kind of best practices for this specific task?
I found no documentation for this matter.